# How do I repair the finish on my bathroom faucet?

Tags: tap

I was attempting to clean the hard water stains off the matte black tap in my tub with Bar Keeper’s Friend and ended up peeling off some of the surface (see orangey bits in photo). Lesson learned not to do that again.

Is there a paint I can buy to fix this?

[image: photo of tap]

Comment: Next time try a touch of vinegar/or similar and paper towels.  Hard to tell what type of paint to use without knowing the material it is made from, but you might want to look at epoxy paint.

Comment: Even if you get the perfect paint match, you are very unlikely to make the touchup seamless. It will always be an eyesore. It's likely powder-coated.

Comment: To get a good finish without it looking like it's been touched up, your best bet may be to keep going with the BKF until _all_ the finish is removed then repaint the entire thing. It might not match the rest of the fixture, though. Have you considered contacting the manufacturer about purchasing a replacement part with the factory finish?